# DataGridView Selected Row Move UP and DOWN

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, collections, datagridview

How can I allow selected rows in a DataGridView (DGV) to be moved up or down.  I have done this before with a ListView. Unfortunetly, for me, replacing the DGV is not an option (*curses*).  By the way, the DGV datasource is a Generic Collection.

The DGV has two buttons on the side, yes, UP & Down.  Can anyone help point me in the right direction.  I do have the code that I used for the ListView if it'll help (it did not help me).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you programatically change the ordering of the items in your collection, the DGV should reflect that automatically.

Sloppy, half-working example:

```
List<MyObj> foo = DGV.DataSource;
int idx = DGV.SelectedRows[0].Index;
int value = foo[idx];
foo.Remove(value);
foo.InsertAt(idx+1, value)
```

Some of that logic may be wrong, and this may not be the most efficient approach either.  Also, it doesn't take into account multiple row selections.

Hmm, one last thing, if you're using a standard List or Collection this isn't going to go as smoothly.  List and Collection on't emit events that the DGV finds useful for databinding.   You could 'burp' the databinding every time you change the collection, but a better solution would be for you to use a System.ComponentModel.BindingList.  When you change the ordering of the BindingList the DGV should reflect the change automatically.

Comment: Hmm...sorting of the DGV (if you allow it,) may have an affect on your implementation as well.

Comment: I have actually made the change to BindingList. I am currently in the process of reviewing the code to make sure that change does not affect other functionality.  Anyway, I am also leaning towards reordering the collection vs. the grid.

Oh, and by the way it does not allow multiple row selections (my only good news).

Comment: Yeah, the BindingList<T> is slightly different from a List<T>, it doesn't have some of the extra helper-methods that List<T> has.  The biggest one that I've noticed is there it no constructor that accepts an IEnumerable<T> like the List<T> does.

Comment: I went ahead and focused on using BindingList and reordering my collection.  It works like a champ so far (during testing).  I will keep an eye on it and see if works for us going forward.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 43):

Just to expand on Yoopergeek's answer, here's what I have.
I was not using a DataSource (data is being dropped to registry on form close, and reload on form load)

This sample will keep rows from being moved off the grid and lost, and reselect the cell the person was in as well.

To make things simpler for copy / paste, I modified so you need only change "gridTasks" to your DataGridView's name, rather than renaming it throughout the code.

**This solution works only for single cell/row selected.**

```
private void btnUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = gridTasks;
    try
    {
        int totalRows = dgv.Rows.Count;
        // get index of the row for the selected cell
        int rowIndex = dgv.SelectedCells[ 0 ].OwningRow.Index;
        if ( rowIndex == 0 )
            return;
        // get index of the column for the selected cell
        int colIndex = dgv.SelectedCells[ 0 ].OwningColumn.Index;
        DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dgv.Rows[ rowIndex ];
        dgv.Rows.Remove( selectedRow );
        dgv.Rows.Insert( rowIndex - 1, selectedRow );
        dgv.ClearSelection();
        dgv.Rows[ rowIndex - 1 ].Cells[ colIndex ].Selected = true;
    }
    catch { }
}

private void btnDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = gridTasks;
    try
    {
        int totalRows = dgv.Rows.Count;
        // get index of the row for the selected cell
        int rowIndex = dgv.SelectedCells[ 0 ].OwningRow.Index;
        if ( rowIndex == totalRows - 1 )
            return;
        // get index of the column for the selected cell
        int colIndex = dgv.SelectedCells[ 0 ].OwningColumn.Index;
        DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dgv.Rows[ rowIndex ];
        dgv.Rows.Remove( selectedRow );
        dgv.Rows.Insert( rowIndex + 1, selectedRow );
        dgv.ClearSelection();
        dgv.Rows[ rowIndex + 1 ].Cells[ colIndex ].Selected = true; 
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: This is a much better answer than the selected answer.

Comment: Perhaps there is something funky about my DGV but on the down move I had to change (idx == totalRows - 2) into (idx == totalRows - 1) otherwise it would allow the bottom row to be moved off and the next to last row isn't able to move down.  With the change it works flawlessly for me.

Comment: This works flawlessly, thank you. Here the C++ version I used: http://pastebin.com/DwYTRSiy

Comment: What if DGV is bound to a database source, an exception may occur!

Answer (score 12):

This should work. I use a BindingSource instead of binding my List directly to the DataGridView:

```
    private List<MyItem> items = new List<MyItem> {
        new MyItem {Id = 0, Name = "Hello"},
        new MyItem {Id = 1, Name = "World"},
        new MyItem {Id = 2, Name = "Foo"},
        new MyItem {Id = 3, Name = "Bar"},
        new MyItem {Id = 4, Name = "Scott"},
        new MyItem {Id = 5, Name = "Tiger"},
    };

    private BindingSource bs;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bs = new BindingSource(items, string.Empty);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bs.Count <= 1) return; // one or zero elements

        int position = bs.Position;
        if (position <= 0) return;  // already at top

        bs.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;

        MyItem current = (MyItem)bs.Current;
        bs.Remove(current);

        position--;

        bs.Insert(position, current);
        bs.Position = position;

        bs.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
        bs.ResetBindings(false);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bs.Count <= 1) return; // one or zero elements

        int position = bs.Position;
        if (position == bs.Count - 1) return;  // already at bottom

        bs.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;

        MyItem current = (MyItem)bs.Current;
        bs.Remove(current);

        position++;

        bs.Insert(position, current);
        bs.Position = position;

        bs.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
        bs.ResetBindings(false);
    }

    public class MyItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: BindingSource's currency-handling is a plus over using BindingList<T>.

Comment: I like this too.  I am keeping this in mind for next time. Thank you for helping out!

Comment: I added some lines to the example code. If you work with big lists, you can set RaiseListChangedEvents to false (that prevents the datagridview from redrawing itself after you remove or add an item.

Comment: this is briliant!
but has some bugs: 
      if (position <= 0) return;  // already at top

        if (position == bs.Count - 1 || bs.Count-1<0) return;  // already at bottom

because if it was empty, was throwing exceptions

Answer (score 3):

There is a much simpler way that most posts here (in my opinion). Performing the action for an "up" button click is basically just a swap of rows with the one above. If you are controlling the values yourself (as the question was stated) then you just need to swap the values of the rows. Quick and simple!

NOTE: this works only when multiselect is disabled on the datagrid! As you can tell I am only paying attention to item at index 0 in the SelectedRows collection.

Here is what I used:

```
    private void btnUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var row = dgvExportLocations.SelectedRows[0];

        if (row != null && row.Index > 0)
        {
            var swapRow = dgvExportLocations.Rows[row.Index - 1];
            object[] values = new object[swapRow.Cells.Count];

            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in swapRow.Cells)
            {
                values[cell.ColumnIndex] = cell.Value;
                cell.Value = row.Cells[cell.ColumnIndex].Value;
            }

            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                cell.Value = values[cell.ColumnIndex];

            dgvExportLocations.Rows[row.Index - 1].Selected = true;//have the selection follow the moving cell
        }
    }
```

To perform a "down" click you can do the opposite as well, same logic

Answer (score 1):

First fill your datagridview,for example you got table with 3 colums

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("col1");
table.Columns.Add("col2");
table.Columns.Add("col3");
foreach (var i in yourTablesource(db,list,etc))
{
  table.Rows.Add(i.col1, i.col2, i.col2);
}
datagridview1.DataSource = table;
```

Then, on button up click

```
int rowIndex;
private void btnUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rowIndex = datagridview1.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Index;
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    row[0] = datagridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    row[1] = datagridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    row[2] = datagridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    if (rowIndex > 0)
    {
        table.Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndex);
        table.Rows.InsertAt(row, rowIndex - 1);
        datagridview1.ClearSelection();
        datagridview1.Rows[rowIndex - 1].Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Do the same thing for button down, just change `row index` from `rowIndex - 1` to `rowindex + 1` in your `buttonDown_Click` method

Answer (score 1):

```
// Down
DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
int index = 0;

row = dgv.SelectedRows[0];
index = dgv.SelectedRows[0].Index;
dgv.Rows.Remove(dgv.SelectedRows[0]);
dgv.Rows.Insert(index + 1, row);
dgv.ClearSelection();
dgv.Rows[index + 1].Selected = true;

// Up
DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
int index = 0;

row = dgv.SelectedRows[0];
index = dgv.SelectedRows[0].Index;
dgv.Rows.Remove(dgv.SelectedRows[0]);
dgv.Rows.Insert(index-1, row);
dgv.ClearSelection();
dgv.Rows[index - 1].Selected = true;
```

Where dgv is your DataGridView.

Comment: Even code may look self-explanatory, it is always nice to get a short explanation as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for this UP/DOWN button thing and glad that I found this.
Better to put the bs.RaiseListChangedEvents = false statement after the return or it doesn't work all the time.

And in C#3.0 you can add two extension methods to the BindingSource like this:

```
public static class BindingSourceExtension
{
    public static void MoveUp( this BindingSource aBindingSource )
    {
        int position = aBindingSource.Position;
        if (position == 0) return;  // already at top

        aBindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;

        object current = aBindingSource.Current;
        aBindingSource.Remove(current);

        position--;

        aBindingSource.Insert(position, current);
        aBindingSource.Position = position;

        aBindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
        aBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
    }

    public static void MoveDown( this BindingSource aBindingSource )
    {
        int position = aBindingSource.Position;
        if (position == aBindingSource.Count - 1) return;  // already at bottom

        aBindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;

        object current = aBindingSource.Current;
        aBindingSource.Remove(current);

        position++;

        aBindingSource.Insert(position, current);
        aBindingSource.Position = position;

        aBindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
        aBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
    }
}
```

Finally a good use for extension methods instead of all those bad String examples.. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
   DataGridViewRow BeginingRow = new DataGridViewRow();
   int BeginingRowIndex ;   
        private void DataGridView1_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left ||e.RowIndex < 0 ) return;
            if (BeginingRowIndex > e.RowIndex)
            {
                DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(e.RowIndex);
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cellules in BeginingRow.Cells)
                {
                    DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[cellules.ColumnIndex].Value = cellules.Value;
                }
                DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(BeginingRowIndex + 1);

            }
            else
            {
                DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(e.RowIndex +1);
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cellules in BeginingRow.Cells)
                {
                    DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex+1].Cells[cellules.ColumnIndex].Value = cellules.Value;
                }
                DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(BeginingRowIndex);
            }

            DataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.ApplyStyle(BeginingRow.DefaultCellStyle);
            DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
    }

    private void DataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left ||e.RowIndex < 0 ) return;
                BeginingRowIndex = e.RowIndex;
                BeginingRow = DataGridView1.Rows[BeginingRowIndex];
                BeginingRow.DefaultCellStyle = DataGridView1.Rows[BeginingRowIndex].DefaultCellStyle;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void butUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtTemp = gridView.DataSource as DataTable;

    object[] arr = dtTemp.Rows[0].ItemArray;
    for (int i = 1; i < dtTemp.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        dtTemp.Rows[i - 1].ItemArray = dtTemp.Rows[i].ItemArray;
    }
    dtTemp.Rows[dtTemp.Rows.Count - 1].ItemArray = arr;

}
private void butDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtTemp = gridView.DataSource as DataTable;

    object[] arr = dtTemp.Rows[dtTemp.Rows.Count - 1].ItemArray;
    for (int i = dtTemp.Rows.Count - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        dtTemp.Rows[i + 1].ItemArray = dtTemp.Rows[i].ItemArray;
    }
    dtTemp.Rows[0].ItemArray = arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the shortest solution I have found to the problem and I just refactored a little bit the code found in:

http://dotnetspeaks.net/post/Moving-GridView-Rows-Up-Down-in-a-GridView-Control.aspx

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="9pt" runat="server" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" BorderColor="#507CD1" BorderStyle="Solid">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>

<asp:Button ID="btnUp" runat="server" Text="Up" OnClick="btnUp_Click"/>
<asp:Button ID="btnDown" runat="server" Text="Down"  OnClick="btnDown_Click" />
</form>
```

and with code behind...

```
public int SelectedRowIndex { get; set; }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //Test Records  
            GridView1.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(a => new
            {
                FirstName = String.Format("First Name {0}", a),
                LastName = String.Format("Last Name {0}", a),
            });
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }  
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='pointer'";
            e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select row";
            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
        }
    }


    protected void btnUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var rows = GridView1.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Where(a => a != GridView1.SelectedRow).ToList();
        //If First Item, insert at end (rotating positions)  
        if (GridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex.Equals(0))
        {
            rows.Add(GridView1.SelectedRow);
            SelectedRowIndex = GridView1.Rows.Count -1;
        }
        else
        {
            SelectedRowIndex = GridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex - 1;
            rows.Insert(GridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex - 1, GridView1.SelectedRow);
        }
        RebindGrid(rows);
    }

    protected void btnDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var rows = GridView1.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Where(a => a != GridView1.SelectedRow).ToList();
        //If Last Item, insert at beginning (rotating positions)  
        if (GridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex.Equals(GridView1.Rows.Count - 1))
        {
            rows.Insert(0, GridView1.SelectedRow);
            SelectedRowIndex = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            SelectedRowIndex = GridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex + 1;
            rows.Insert(GridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex + 1, GridView1.SelectedRow);
        }
        RebindGrid(rows);
    }

    private void RebindGrid(IEnumerable<GridViewRow> rows)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = rows.Select(a => new
        {
            FirstName = ((Label)a.FindControl("txtFirstName")).Text,
        }).ToList();

        GridView1.SelectedIndex = SelectedRowIndex;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Header 3

private void buttonX8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//down
        {
            DataGridViewX grid = dataGridViewX1;
            try
            {
                int totalRows = grid.Rows.Count;
                int idx = grid.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Index;
                if (idx == totalRows - 1 )
                    return;
                int col = grid.SelectedCells[0].OwningColumn.Index;
                DataGridViewRowCollection rows = grid.Rows;
                DataGridViewRow row = rows[idx];
                rows.Remove(row);
                rows.Insert(idx + 1, row);
                grid.ClearSelection();
                grid.Rows[idx + 1].Cells[col].Selected = true;

```
      private void buttonX8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//down
    {
        DataGridViewX grid = dataGridViewX1;
        try
        {
            int totalRows = grid.Rows.Count;
            int idx = grid.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Index;
            if (idx == totalRows - 1 )
                return;
            int col = grid.SelectedCells[0].OwningColumn.Index;
            DataGridViewRowCollection rows = grid.Rows;
            DataGridViewRow row = rows[idx];
            rows.Remove(row);
            rows.Insert(idx + 1, row);
            grid.ClearSelection();
            grid.Rows[idx + 1].Cells[col].Selected = true;

        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

SchlaWiener's answer worked well, and I just wanna add something to it:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //The button to move up
{
    int position = bs.Position;

    //.......neglected.......

    dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    dataGridView1.Rows[position].Selected = true;
    bs.MovePrevious();

}
```

Adding those 3 lines at the bottom to also make the selection move (both bindingSource and dataGridView), so that we can continuously click the bottom to move a row up.

For moving down just call bs.MoveNext()

(I have not enough reputation to post as comment yet)

Comment: Welcome to SO:SE. Well... as you know a comment posted as a answer will eventually be deleted, even if they are useful like yours. Getting 50 rep is not big deal, just start answering a couple of questions.

Answer (score 0):

data bound solution with multi-selection support, use SharpDevelop 4.4 to convert to C#.

```
<Extension()>
Sub MoveSelectionUp(dgv As DataGridView)
    If dgv.CurrentCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    dgv.CurrentCell.OwningRow.Selected = True
    Dim items = DirectCast(dgv.DataSource, BindingSource).List
    Dim selectedIndices = dgv.SelectedRows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).Select(Function(row) row.Index).Sort
    Dim indexAbove = selectedIndices(0) - 1
    If indexAbove = -1 Then Exit Sub
    Dim itemAbove = items(indexAbove)
    items.RemoveAt(indexAbove)
    Dim indexLastItem = selectedIndices(selectedIndices.Count - 1)

    If indexLastItem = items.Count Then
        items.Add(itemAbove)
    Else
        items.Insert(indexLastItem + 1, itemAbove)
    End If
End Sub

<Extension()>
Sub MoveSelectionDown(dgv As DataGridView)
    If dgv.CurrentCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    dgv.CurrentCell.OwningRow.Selected = True
    Dim items = DirectCast(dgv.DataSource, BindingSource).List
    Dim selectedIndices = dgv.SelectedRows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).Select(Function(row) row.Index).Sort
    Dim indexBelow = selectedIndices(selectedIndices.Count - 1) + 1
    If indexBelow >= items.Count Then Exit Sub
    Dim itemBelow = items(indexBelow)
    items.RemoveAt(indexBelow)
    Dim indexAbove = selectedIndices(0) - 1
    items.Insert(indexAbove + 1, itemBelow)
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    private void buttonX9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//up
    {

        DataGridViewX grid = dataGridViewX1;
        try
        {
            int totalRows = grid.Rows.Count;
            int idx = grid.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Index;
            if (idx == 0)
                return;
            int col = grid.SelectedCells[0].OwningColumn.Index;
            DataGridViewRowCollection rows = grid.Rows;
            DataGridViewRow row = rows[idx];
            rows.Remove(row);
            rows.Insert(idx - 1, row);
            grid.ClearSelection();
            grid.Rows[idx - 1].Cells[col].Selected = true;

        }
        catch { }

    }
```