# Move up or down little complex DataGridView rows with multi-selection

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView like this:

[image]

Now, In **C#** or else **VB.Net**, with a button, I would like to move up or down one position the selected rows, how I could do it?. The multi selection requisite complicate me this.

The files that appear in the DataGridView will be combined into a single executable file, then, the files will be executed in the order of the "**Order**" column, so the "**Order**" value should be inmutable when moving rows up or down.

I'm not using any data source.

---

I've tried to analyze this sample from **MSDN**, it consists in some extension methods, but it takes a datatable and datasource, I don't have any dissapoint to use a datatable and datasource but just I don't know how to adapt the code-sample for my DataGridView. 
Anyways the sample does not support multi selection:

**[Move rows up/down and remember order for DataGridView and ListBoxs data bound](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Move-rows-updown-and-987fe786)**

I also have seen some C# questions about this on StackOverflow but they asks for single row selection:

**[How to move gridview selected row up/down on KeyUp or Keydown press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232943/how-to-move-gridview-selected-row-up-down-on-keyup-or-keydown-press)**

**[DataGridView Selected Row Move UP and DOWN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012708/datagridview-selected-row-move-up-and-down)**

Then, I don't have an starting point, just these methods to move a SINGLE row that also does not preserve the **Order** value, if someone could guide me to extend the functionality for my needs:
    Private Sub Button_MoveUp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles Button_MoveUp.Click

```
    Me.MoveUpSelectedRows(Me.DataGridView_Files)

End Sub

Private Sub Button_MoveDown_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
Handles Button_MoveDown.Click

    Me.MoveDownSelectedRows(Me.DataGridView_Files)

End Sub

Private Sub MoveUpSelectedRows(ByVal dgv As DataGridView)

    Dim curRowIndex As Integer = dgv.CurrentCell.RowIndex
    Dim newRowIndex As Integer = curRowIndex - 1

    Dim curColIndex As Integer = dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
    Dim curRow As DataGridViewRow = dgv.CurrentRow

    If (dgv.SelectedCells.Count > 0) AndAlso (newRowIndex >= 0) Then

        With dgv
            .Rows.Remove(curRow)
            .Rows.Insert(newRowIndex, curRow)
            .CurrentCell = dgv(curColIndex, newRowIndex)
        End With

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub MoveDownSelectedRows(ByVal dgv As DataGridView)

    Dim curRowIndex As Integer = dgv.CurrentCell.RowIndex
    Dim newRowIndex As Integer = curRowIndex + 1

    Dim curColIndex As Integer = dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
    Dim curRow As DataGridViewRow = dgv.CurrentRow

    If (dgv.SelectedCells.Count > 0) AndAlso (dgv.Rows.Count > newRowIndex) Then

        With dgv
            .Rows.Remove(curRow)
            .Rows.Insert(newRowIndex, curRow)
            .CurrentCell = dgv(curColIndex, newRowIndex)
        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

---

> UPDATE

I'm trying @Plutonix approach (with a little modification), the only problem is that it does not move properly the selected rows to UP direction.

Steps to reprduce the issue:

1. Select two rows that are together (eg. row index 2 and row index 3, NOT row index 2 and row index 4)
2. Try to move the rows to UP direction.

How I could fix it?.

```
Public Enum MoveDirection As Integer
    Up = -1
    Down = 1
End Enum

Private Sub MoveRows(ByVal dgv As DataGridView, ByVal moveDirection As MoveDirection)

    Dim rows As DataGridViewRowCollection = dgv.Rows

    ' row index
    Dim thisRow As DataGridViewRow

    ' put selection back
    Dim selectedRows As New List(Of Integer)

    ' max rows
    Dim lastRowIndex As Integer =
        If(dgv.AllowUserToAddRows,
           rows.Count - 2,
           rows.Count - 1)



    For n As Integer = lastRowIndex To 0 Step -1

        If Not rows(n).IsNewRow Then

            If rows(n).Selected Then

                selectedRows.Add(n)

                MsgBox(n)

                Select Case moveDirection

                    Case Main.MoveDirection.Down
                        If ((n + moveDirection) <= lastRowIndex) AndAlso (n + moveDirection >= 0) AndAlso rows(n + moveDirection).Selected = False Then

                            selectedRows(selectedRows.Count - 1) = (n + moveDirection)
                            thisRow = rows(n)
                            rows.Remove(thisRow)

                            rows.Insert(n + moveDirection, thisRow)

                        End If

                    Case Main.MoveDirection.Up

                        If ((n + moveDirection) <= lastRowIndex) Then

                            MsgBox(selectedRows(selectedRows.Count - 1))
                            selectedRows(selectedRows.Count - 1) = (n + moveDirection)
                            thisRow = rows(n)
                            rows.Remove(thisRow)

                            rows.Insert(n + moveDirection, thisRow)

                        End If

                End Select

            End If

        End If

    Next n

    ' reselect the original selected rows
    For n As Integer = 0 To lastRowIndex

        dgv.Rows(n).Selected = selectedRows.Contains(n)

        ' renumber the order (optional & unknown, but trivial)
        dgv.Rows(n).Cells(0).Value = (n + 1)

    Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: what do you mean "the "Order" value should be inmutable"?  When these 2 rows move down one, after are they (2, 4) or (3, 5)?  Immutable would mean they do not change, which would mean the visible order would not match the number shown for the Order.  That would seem to be confusing.

Comment: Yes, visible index should not change, you understood perfect what I mean , don't worry :) and thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Updated)
You need to iterate the rows collection, test if each is selected, then swap rows.  In order to keep 2 selected rows from swapping with each other when they get to the top or bottom, a separate Up and Down method are needed.

```vb
' list of hash codes of the selected rows
Private Function GetSelectedRows() As List(Of Integer)
    Dim selR As New List(Of Integer)

    ' have to clear selected so the NEXT row 
    ' doesnt cause odd behavior
    For n As Integer = 0 To dgv.Rows.Count - 1
        If dgv.Rows(n).IsNewRow = False AndAlso dgv.Rows(n).Selected Then
            selR.Add(dgv.Rows(n).GetHashCode)
            dgv.Rows(n).Selected = False
        End If
    Next
    Return selR
End Function

' restore original selected rows
Private Sub SetSelectedRows(selRows As List(Of Integer))

    For n As Integer = 0 To dgv.Rows.Count - 1
        If dgv.Rows(n).IsNewRow = False Then
            dgv.Rows(n).Selected = selRows.Contains(dgv.Rows(n).GetHashCode)
            ' reset Order col:
            dgv.Rows(n).Cells(0).Value = n + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub MoveRowsUp()
    ' short ref
    Dim rows As DataGridViewRowCollection = dgv.Rows
    ' row index
    Dim thisRow As DataGridViewRow
    ' put selection back
    Dim selectedRows As List(Of Integer)
    ' max rows
    Dim LastRow = If(dgv.AllowUserToAddRows, rows.Count - 2, rows.Count - 1)

    selectedRows = GetSelectedRows()

    For n As Int32 = 0 To LastRow
        If rows(n).IsNewRow = False Then

            If (selectedRows.Contains(rows(n).GetHashCode)) AndAlso (n - 1 >= 0) AndAlso
                (selectedRows.Contains(rows(n - 1).GetHashCode) = False) Then

                thisRow = rows(n)
                rows.Remove(thisRow)
                rows.Insert(n - 1, thisRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    SetSelectedRows(selectedRows)

End Sub

Private Sub MoveRowsDn()
    Dim rows As DataGridViewRowCollection = dgv.Rows
    Dim thisRow As DataGridViewRow
    Dim selectedRows As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim LastRow = If(dgv.AllowUserToAddRows, rows.Count - 2, rows.Count - 1)

    selectedRows = GetSelectedRows()

    For n As Int32 = LastRow To 0 Step -1

        If rows(n).IsNewRow = False Then
            If (selectedRows.Contains(rows(n).GetHashCode)) AndAlso (n + 1 <= LastRow) AndAlso
                         (selectedRows.Contains(rows(n + 1).GetHashCode) = False) Then
                thisRow = rows(n)
                rows.Remove(thisRow)
                rows.Insert(n + 1, thisRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    SetSelectedRows(selectedRows)

End Sub
```

Usage:

```vb
 MoveRowsUp()
 ' move down:
 MoveRowsDn()
```

Moving the rows causes the dgv to reset the selections.  The methods first go thru and get a list of the HashCodes of the selected rows, then at the end resets each `Row.Selected` property based on that.

The code changes the value of Cell(0) so the order and Order column match (which means the Order column value *is* mutable).

Moving checks to see both if this row is at the end *OR* if the row at the destination is also selected.  This prevents rows from swapping places when they get to the top or bottom.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Note that when "Zalgo" got to the bottom (meaning 3 and 5 were selected), the other one could still move down one, so it did while "Ziggy" stayed put.  The ability of "Ziggy(3)" to move down or not is based on the next row/index (only) - the next row is not beyond the bottom *AND* not selected so it can still move down 1, while "Zalgo (5)" could not.

Comment: thanks this is exactlly what I need, but it does not works for UP direction, please see my update, I added a little modification but the original code has the same issue.

Comment: `Note that when "Zalgo" got to the bottom, the other one could still move down one, so it did while "Zalgo" stayed put and selected. ` Yes, I've written a temporal fix for that you can see in the update above, because I consider it a behavior problem, the best thing would be that for example if you had selected rows 2,4 and 5, and you move rows to down, only row 2 moves down to 3, so 4 and 5 stays in the same lasts indexes, I mean row 4 and 5 are already at the bottom, them should not still able to move down, only row 2 should move down in that case. I figured out how to do it without success.

Comment: The main problem is about the UP direction as I mentioned in the udate, the behavior problem about superposition of top or bottom rows are a minor issue, but please if you could figure how to improve it in that way then it would be a great (maybe the better efficient) datagridview row-move mechanism!.

Comment: Up works fine for me. 2, 4, 5 also works but it IS a little odd.  When 4 is tested, it CAN move down, so it does. If you dont want that add a `AndAlso rows(n + direction).Selected = False` to the test so that if the next position is Selected, it is skipped.  Add that to the end of the 2 AndAlso already there so that it is skipped when (n + direction > LastRow).  That might fix the 2+3 problem too - I will look at side by side rows in the morning.

Comment: Wait,  Are you saying that (3, 5) move as a unit, and 3 cant go down because 5 is at the bottom - ie one thing stays between them?

Comment: `add a AndAlso rows(n + direction).Selected = False to the test so that if the next position is Selected, it is skipped.` thankyou that solved the problem now I can delete the temp fix, but the UP direction is not working as I mentioned. if I have two rows together and selected it only moves one row. please, see this short video where I demonstrate it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1yaL3Vfs9qU&feature=youtu.be

Comment: the update posted is actually quite different that yesterday's post.  (BTW `this video is private`)

Comment: I didn't noticed it, sorry. But with your new modification now there is two different problems, first problem is that the order-column is not preserved anymore, and second problem is that it moves unselected rows :-/

Answer (score 1):

This is my final code, all thanks goes to @Plutonix, I just translated the logic to extension methods and also extended the original functionality to automate a cell preservation by giving a collection of cell indexes to preserve its values:

```
#Region " Members Summary "

' · Public Methods
'
'     MoveSelectedRows(direction)
'     MoveSelectedRows(direction, preserveCellsIndex)

#End Region

#Region " Option Statements "

Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off

#End Region

#Region " Imports "

Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Windows.Forms

#End Region

''' <summary>
''' Contains sofisticated extension methods for a <see cref="DataGridView"/> control.
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Module DataGridViewExtensions

#Region " Enumerations "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Specifies a direction for a move operation of a rows collection.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Enum RowMoveDirection As Integer

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Move row up.
        ''' </summary>
        Up = 0

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Move row down.
        ''' </summary>
        Down = 1

    End Enum

#End Region

#Region " Public Extension Methods "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Moves up or down the selected row(s) of the current <see cref="DataGridView"/>.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender">The <see cref="DataGridView"/>.</param>
    ''' <param name="direction">The row-move direction.</param>
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    <Extension>
    Public Sub MoveSelectedRows(ByVal sender As DataGridView,
                                ByVal direction As RowMoveDirection)

        DoRowsMove(sender, direction)

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Moves up or down the selected row(s) of the current <see cref="DataGridView"/>.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender">The <see cref="DataGridView"/>.</param>
    ''' <param name="direction">The row-move direction.</param>
    ''' <param name="preserveCellsIndex">A sequence of cell indexes to preserve its cell values when moving the row(s).</param>
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    <Extension>
    Public Sub MoveSelectedRows(ByVal sender As DataGridView,
                                ByVal direction As RowMoveDirection,
                                ByVal preserveCellsIndex As IEnumerable(Of Integer))

        DoRowsMove(sender, direction, preserveCellsIndex)

    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Private Methods "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Moves up or down the selected row(s) of the specified <see cref="DataGridView"/>.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="dgv">The <see cref="DataGridView"/>.</param>
    ''' <param name="direction">The row-move direction.</param>
    ''' <param name="preserveCellsIndex">Optionally, a sequence of cell indexes to preserve its cell values when moving the row(s).</param>
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Private Sub DoRowsMove(ByVal dgv As DataGridView,
                           ByVal direction As RowMoveDirection,
                           Optional ByVal preserveCellsIndex As IEnumerable(Of Integer) = Nothing)

        ' Keeps tracks of a cell value to preserve, to swap them when moving rows.
        Dim oldCellValue As Object
        Dim newCellValue As Object

        ' Short row collection reference.
        Dim rows As DataGridViewRowCollection = dgv.Rows

        ' Keeps track of the current row.
        Dim curRow As DataGridViewRow

        ' The maximum row index.
        Dim lastRowIndex As Integer =
            If(dgv.AllowUserToAddRows,
               rows.Count - 2,
               rows.Count - 1)

        ' List of hash codes of the selected rows.
        Dim selectedRows As New List(Of Integer)

        ' Get the hash codes of the selected rows
        For i As Integer = 0 To (rows.Count - 1)
            If (rows(i).IsNewRow = False) AndAlso (rows(i).Selected) Then
                selectedRows.Add(rows(i).GetHashCode)
                rows(i).Selected = False
            End If
        Next i

        ' Move the selected rows up or down.
        Select Case direction

            Case RowMoveDirection.Up
                For i As Integer = 0 To lastRowIndex

                    If Not rows(i).IsNewRow Then

                        If (selectedRows.Contains(rows(i).GetHashCode)) AndAlso
                           (i - 1 >= 0) AndAlso
                           (Not selectedRows.Contains(rows(i - 1).GetHashCode)) Then

                            curRow = rows(i)
                            rows.Remove(curRow)
                            rows.Insert(i - 1, curRow)

                            If preserveCellsIndex IsNot Nothing Then

                                For Each cellIndex As Integer In preserveCellsIndex
                                    oldCellValue = curRow.Cells(cellIndex).Value
                                    newCellValue = rows(i).Cells(cellIndex).Value

                                    rows(i).Cells(cellIndex).Value = oldCellValue
                                    curRow.Cells(cellIndex).Value = newCellValue
                                Next cellIndex

                            End If

                        End If

                    End If

                Next i

            Case RowMoveDirection.Down
                For i As Integer = lastRowIndex To 0 Step -1

                    If Not rows(i).IsNewRow Then

                        If (selectedRows.Contains(rows(i).GetHashCode)) AndAlso
                           (i + 1 <= lastRowIndex) AndAlso
                           (Not selectedRows.Contains(rows(i + 1).GetHashCode)) Then

                            curRow = rows(i)
                            rows.Remove(curRow)
                            rows.Insert(i + 1, curRow)

                            If preserveCellsIndex IsNot Nothing Then

                                For Each cellIndex As Integer In preserveCellsIndex
                                    oldCellValue = curRow.Cells(cellIndex).Value
                                    newCellValue = rows(i).Cells(cellIndex).Value

                                    rows(i).Cells(cellIndex).Value = oldCellValue
                                    curRow.Cells(cellIndex).Value = newCellValue
                                Next cellIndex

                            End If

                        End If

                    End If

                Next i

        End Select

        ' Restore selected rows.
        For i As Integer = 0 To (rows.Count - 1)

            If Not rows(i).IsNewRow Then
                rows(i).Selected = selectedRows.Contains(rows(i).GetHashCode)
            End If

        Next i

    End Sub

#End Region

End Module
```