# Improve DataGridView rows managing

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

> SCENARIO

I'm manually filling a **DataGridView** with a **DataGridViewRow** collection:

[image]

I created the columns at design time in the GUI builder of Visual Studio.

- First column takes an **Integer** value, its a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`.
- Second column takes an **Icon** object, its a `DataGridViewImageColumn`.
- Third column takes a **String** value, its a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`.
- Fourth takes an **String** value, its a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.

So, when I want to add a new row, I do this:

```
Dim dgvr As New DataGridViewRow
With dgvr
    .CreateCells(MyDataGridView)
    .Cells(0).Value = An Integer value
    .Cells(1).Value = An Icon object
    .Cells(2).Value = An String value
    .Cells(3).Value = An existing ComBoBox item name.
End With

MyDataGridView.Rows.Add(dgvr)
```

> QUESTION

My intention is to follow good programming practices, then, to avoid this kind of interaction with the **UI**, I just would preffer to use and manage a `DataSource`, then how I can create a `DataTable` that takes the same type of values to set it as the `DataSource` of the control?. Is it possible?.

If not, just what can I do to manage a `DataSource` instead of directlly manage the rows collection of the control?

In general, how I can improve what I'm doing for gain better efficiency?.

Comment: Create a `DataTable` with the correct `DataTypes` for the columns, add your row's to the `DataTable` and then set it's `.DataSource` to the table.

Comment: Rather than a DataTable - create a DGVItem class for the data and use a `List(Of DGVitem)` or a BindingList.  Use them as the DGV DataSource.  There is no advantage to a datatable in this case.  note that you will need to rewrite your MoveUp/Dn method no matter what you do (I started to suggest that on the other question but...)

Comment: @Plutonix I would agree with creating a class by all means. If you don't mind, why is there no advantage to a DataTable, why? Why is the class and list any better than the DataTable if you don't mind me asking? Also I would personally use a dictionary so I could update easily if need to be, when using a list there's no key/value to look to...

Comment: @436f6465786572, I meant no advantage to a DT over a List and Class.  A DT would work.  What you might not know is [the other aspect of this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30834186/1070452).  That is much easier with a List than dealing with a DT, DT.RowsCollection etc

Comment: @436f6465786572, actually, I was not trying to contradict you - I sort of thought the OP was wanting a DT rather than DataSource.  I'd go with a DT if the data was in a DB or a case where the DT columns, types etc would be created, typed and filled for me.

Comment: @Plutonix I know you weren't trying to contradict me by all means. I was just wanting to know your view on it :)

Comment: Thanks for all comments, Initially I thinked in a DataTable because the question that Plutonix has linked, I'm using that code for a normal DataGridViewRowCollection , but the original code from Microsoft samples is designed to use it with a DataTable, then I thinked in that kind of container to improve my app, but if it would be better to use a custom class then I don't have any dissapoint to do it, just I need a little help with a sample class and/or sample binding to start with it because I dont have experience with this, its a headache the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn column type.

Comment: So, I suppose that I should write a class with 4 public members for 4 cells (int32, icon, string, and an Enumeration) and then...? whats next?. PS: But If later I also should ask for a moverows up/down for this custom class then I really preffer to use a Datatable because I have the code sample from MSDN

Comment: the code you have for the Up/Dn will work fine with a List/Collection with just a few tweaks  (mainly change `rows` to `dgvList`).  If you use a DT, you'll also end up having to fish the pieces of data out for however they are used.  A DT would be great (**better** than a List) if the data came from a DB and was going back there, but it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`what can I do to manage a DataSource instead of directlly manage the rows collection of the control`

A Class and a collection are pretty easy to implement as a `DataSource` and will also it will be pretty easy to modify your MoveUp/Dn methods for it.

```
Class DGVItem
    Public Property Index As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Color As String

    ' this will make the up/dn method simpler
    Public Property Selected As Boolean

    Public Sub New(i As Integer, n As String, v As String)
        Index = i
        Name = n
        Color = v
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Format("{0} ({1})", Name, Index)
    End Function

End Class

' collection source:
Private dgvList As BindingList(Of DGVItem)
```

After you fill the collection with the items, set it as the DGV's `DataSource`:

```
...
dgvList.Add(New DGVItem(ndx, filename, Compression.Default))
...
myDGV.DataSource = dgvList
```

You also need to tell the DGV which property to display in which column.  The DGV will `AutoGenerateColumns`, but you probably already created some using the Designer (IDE).  Open the columns editor and for each column, find `DataPropertyName` and type in the Item property name to display in that column.  For instance, Col 0 would be `Index` or `Order`.  If you do not add a column for the new `Selected` property, it wont show.

In cases where you let the DGV auto-create columns from the `DataSource`, after you bind the source to the control, you can remove any unwanted columns (such as `Selected`). Note that it will create columns but it will not name them.

At this point, you would be utilizing the "View" aspect of the DGV - it is displaying the data contained elsewhere.  As such, you no longer manipulate the DGV rows (such as MoveRow Up/Dn or deleting a row) - that will result in an error.  Instead you manage the `BindingList` - changes to it will automatically display in the DGV.

Finally, note that the DGV will update the `BindingList` contents when the user performs edits.  If they pick a different compression for  item 3, `dgvList(2).Compression` will be updated for you.